# How to export all ontology mappings from Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I want to review my ontology and I'd like to check how the datasets contributing to the ontology are mapped to ontology objects at scale. Reviewing mappings in the UI doesn't work with my scale.

I can get the definition of my ontology, but I don't see how are the columns of the datasets mapped to ontology.

tried: exporting ontology, inspecting UI

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with the current *APIs*. However, you can still get this information in bulk.

First, go to the Ontology Manager app and then navigate to the Advanced section of the particular ontology you are interested in. At the bottom of the page you should see an option to Export Ontology (assuming your user has the correct permissions).

Next, export the ontology. It will download as json file. Within each object type of the ontology you will find a `datasources` array. There you can find the rid(s) of the dataset(s) you're seeking. You will probably need to write a script to do this at scale.

Comment: thanks a lot. However, what I'm after is retrieving how different columns from each dataset are mapped to the ontology attributes. Could I perhaps reverse engineer the calls that Ontology App is making to do this?

I'm not looking for the production-proof solution, only something that gets me what I need once to run my analysis

Comment: I think I understand now. In the ontology export file each object type has an array of properties. Each property has both a `datasourceRid` field and a `column` field. I believe that the `column` field is what you're looking for.